# MS Bot Framework : migration from Bot Builder 3.8.0 to 4.2.2

Tags: botframework

I recently upgraded `Microsoft.Bot.Builder` from version `3.8.0` to Version `4.2.2` (latest stable). Since then, everything got messed up. None of the Luis namespaces are getting resolved. For e.g., in Dialogs, I had below code:

```
[LuisModel("<KEY>", "<KEU>")]
    public class TestDialog : LuisDialog<object>
    {
}
```

but after upgrade, `LuisModel` does not resolve. I also added `"Microsoft.Bot.Builder.AI.Luis"` but it does not help!

Answer (score 1):

The Bot Builder SDK was re-written between versions 3 and 4.  There are many breaking changes.  One of which is that there is no longer a `LUISDialog`.  The V3 SDK is still maintained and supported, with the most recent version as of 2.25.2019 being https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Bot.Builder/3.20.1

Some guidance for converting from V3 to V4 can be found here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/migration/migration-about